# Weld Circular Dependency of normal scoped beans

Tags: cdi, jboss-weld, weld

I'm using JBoss EAP 6.4 (and Weld 1.1.28) and trying to get rid of Seam 2. One part of that is switching over to CDI. I get the following (anonymized) error:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001443 Pseudo scoped bean
has circular dependencies. Dependency path
[Managed Bean [A] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named],
 Managed Bean [B] with qualifiers [@Default @Any],
 Managed Bean [C] with qualifiers [@Default @Any],
 Managed Bean [D] with qualifiers [@Default @Any],
 Managed Bean [C] with qualifiers [@Default @Any]]
```

Every single one of these is `@SessionScoped`, however, so it seems like this should work since `@SessionScoped` is a "normal" scope. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`?

Comment: D'oh! Yep, I had been importing from javax.faces.bean. Put that in as an answer and I'll check it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@SessionScoped` for CDI is `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`. If you happen to annotate class with `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` then your class is not managed by CDI. When you try to `@Inject` it then it will be `@Dependent` pseudo-scoped.